# How to parse a method declaration?

Tags: parsing, go

I'm trying to parse a method declaration. Basically I need to get the syntax node of the receiver base type (`type hello`) and the return types (`notype` and `error`). The `ast` package seems straightforward but for some reason I don't get the data I need (i.e. the fields are reported nil).

The only useful data seems provided only in `Object -> Decl` field  which is of type `interface{}`  so I don't think I can serialize it.

Any help would be appreciated. Code below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
)

func main() {
    // src is the input for which we want to inspect the AST.
    src := `
package mypack
// type hello is a cool type
type hello string

// type notype is not that cool
type notype int

// func printme is like nothing else.
func (x *hello)printme(s string)(notype, error){
    return 0, nil
}
`
    // Create the AST by parsing src.
    fset := token.NewFileSet() // positions are relative to fset
    f, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "src.go", src, 0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Inspect the AST and find our function
    var mf ast.FuncDecl
    ast.Inspect(f, func(n ast.Node) bool {
        switch x := n.(type) {
        case *ast.FuncDecl:
            mf = *x
        }
        return true
    })

    if mf.Recv != nil {
        fmt.Printf("\n receivers:")
        for _, v := range mf.Recv.List {
            fmt.Printf(",tag %v", v.Tag)
            for _, xv := range v.Names {
                fmt.Printf("name %v, decl %v, data %v, type %v",
                    xv.Name, xv.Obj.Decl, xv.Obj.Data, xv.Obj.Type)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/U0q9Un0Icu)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the type you need to look at the `Type` attribute which could be an `ast.StarExpr` or an `ast.Ident`.

Here take a look at [this](http://play.golang.org/p/sn0-MioJel) :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
)

func main() {
    // src is the input for which we want to inspect the AST.
    src := `
package mypack
// type hello is a cool type
type hello string

// type notype is not that cool
type notype int

// printme is like nothing else.
func (x *hello)printme(s string)(notype, error){
    return 0, nil
}
`
    // Create the AST by parsing src.
    fset := token.NewFileSet() // positions are relative to fset
    f, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "src.go", src, 0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Inspect the AST and find our function
    var mf ast.FuncDecl
    ast.Inspect(f, func(n ast.Node) bool {
        switch x := n.(type) {
        case *ast.FuncDecl:
            mf = *x
        }
        return true
    })

    if mf.Recv != nil {
        for _, v := range mf.Recv.List {
            fmt.Print("recv type : ")
            switch xv := v.Type.(type) {
            case *ast.StarExpr:
                if si, ok := xv.X.(*ast.Ident); ok {
                    fmt.Println(si.Name)
                }
            case *ast.Ident:
                fmt.Println(xv.Name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea why the method receiver type has to use a generic {{interface}} type  and not ``StarExpr`` ? There doesn't seem to be more ways to declare a method.