# Access package comment from inside Go program?

Tags: go, docstring

Is it possible to get package comment from inside of Go program? The equivalent Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Program v1.0
"""
print(__doc__)
```

Comment: The `go/doc` package may help. http://golang.org/pkg/go/doc/#ToHTML

Comment: @Intermernet, I still don't see a way to access the docstring of the current file.

Comment: @techtonik you can't do that on runtime unless you manually load the go file (source code; e.g. main.go ) . You can do that with the parser package and you can extract the comments with the ast package. I had a question which may help you  http://stackoverflow.com/q/28246970/613453 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go is not an interpreted language. The source code representation of a program is not part of a compiled Go program and cannot be generated from a compiled Go program. What you want is not possible without external tools that embed the parts of the source you want into the binary.

Comment: Looks like its impossible, indeed. Prooflink - http://blog.golang.org/godoc-documenting-go-code